# Unexplained computer crash via hardware

Tags: boot, multi-boot, desktop-computer

I have a very weird hardware problem (I assume), my computer crashes sometimes when it is running. This is not the most weird part, when I boot the computer the GRUB 2.0 boot loader is displayed. After passing the boot loader and booting Windows 7 or Ubuntu 10.10 it crashes.

After several attempts it boots and works correctly (most of the time). So, my first solution was to create a delay in the GRUB boot loader because it seemed that it needed some time to "warm-up". Now, the problem is worse and I should add an addition delay to the GRUB boot loader.

- The computer needs time to "warm-up"
- If it is "warm" the computer crashes at the login screen of Ubuntu and Windows
- Sometimes it crashes when I got it to run, but no logic found here
- The computer never crashed at the GRUB bootloader
- Memory tests didn't found any problems
- The values of the power seem to be correct
- Temperatures seems to be okey aswell.
- I replaced the videocard

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you boot to a live CD? Have you pulled and re-seated all cards and memory?

Comment: Check the capacitors on the motherboard for swelling and bulging, it can also be a bad PSU.

Comment: @JohnDR the live CD gives the same result, crash at the login screen.

Comment: @Moab, is there a way to log the PSU voltages?

Comment: Not that I know of, If I eliminate everything else, I replace the PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is what JohnDR says and try booting to a disk and see if that does something different, that will tell you hardware or software.

If it still fails, I would test the PSU first, as it is easiest to test.

If you have a second system and no boot disc. Pull the boot drive and put in a different machine. Even with no drivers for the different hardware Windows 7 should load. If it loads look at your Board/Processor/PSU. If it fails look at your software.

Comment: There are a number of software apps that will measure PSU voltages but they all run in Ubuntu or Windows, they are not boot programs. If you are going to test voltages get a Volt meter and have some fun. you should be able to find acceptable levels for your PSU on the web.